# Calling HTTP post method inside for loop which should return multiple times

Tags: angular, for-loop, return

I have a for loop like below

```
    for (let i = 0; i < customAttributes.length; i++){
          if(customAttributes[i].action === 'add') {
            return this.httpc.post(url, customAttributes[i], {headers: httpOptions.headers})
            .pipe(map(res => res));
          }
    }
```

It will return when the match found and the loop breaks there. But how can return multiple times when the `if` condition matches multiple times. I may have `customAttributes[i].action === 'add'` condition `true` for multiple objects, not only one. I want to make the `http` call multiple times without breaking the loop. Please suggest an advice on this.

Comment: Why don't you _filter_ the array, then research how to do multiple things in series or parallel with RxJS?

Comment: As mentioned by @jonrsharpe you should rather make ONE http call and then filter the results. Otherwise you would possibly do n api request which leads to terrible performance.

Comment: That wasn't what I was saying, but if you _can_ do it in one request that would likely be more efficient, yes.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion :** Instead of making multiple calls for the same type of payload object. You can pass an array of objects instead of separate object each time.

**Step 1 :** Filtered out the array with the objects contains `action: add`

```js
let customAttributes = [{
    id: 1,
    action: 'add'
}, {
    id: 2,
    action: 'xyz'
}, {
    id: 3,
    action: 'xyz'
}, {
    id: 4,
    action: 'add'
}, {
    id: 5,
    action: 'add'
}];

let filteredAttributes = customAttributes.filter((attribute) => attribute.action === 'add')

console.log(filteredAttributes)
```

**Step 2 :** Pass the whole filtered array `filteredAttributes` in the API request payload.

```
this.httpc.post(url, filteredAttributes, {headers: httpOptions.headers})
```